# Updating Linq2Sql object gives exception in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

net MVC Web Application. I have a database where i have made my model, i use Linq2SQL to build my Business Logic Layer. In my application i have a customer object, when i call my "editCystomer" page i pass in a Customer to populate the textBoxes:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        [Authorize]
        public ViewResult EditCustomer(string id)
        {
            int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            CustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();
            return View(repository.Load(customerId));
        }
```

When the user has changed in the textboxes i save my changed customer like this:

```
AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult EditCustomer(Customer customer)
        {         
            ValidateCustomer(customer);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();
                repository.Save(customer);
                return RedirectToAction("CreateCustomerDone");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Nothing fancy or unexpected so far, however in my save method:

```
public void Save(Customer customer)
        {
            if (customer.Id > 0)
                sdc.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepChanges, customer);
            else
                sdc.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);

            sdc.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

...im getting an exception in my save (the update) that it cannot refresh the object (An object specified for refresh is not recognized. ). I have done this a million times before in other setups, how come its failing now? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer object you're sending to `Save()` is not part of the `DataContext`. You need to either get the object again, then call the `Refresh()`.

Or you can do the following:

```
public void Save(Customer customer)
{
    if (customer.Id > 0)
    {
        Customer orig = sdc.Customers.GetOriginalEntityState(customer);

       if(orig == null)
            sdc.Attach(customer);

        sdc.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepChanges, customer);
    }
    else
        sdc.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);

    sdc.SubmitChanges();
}
```